# html page, changing language

Tags: html, web, lang

Question about Language Settings for Website

For Example:
I have 3 web pages connected with hyperlinks(from page01 --> page02/page03 and back) . I want to change the language on page 1. (i. e. with a Select Button). 

After the language change , all 3 pages should show the content in the new language.

Can the Server send a kind of language file which each Website can search for the  language tags?

Comment: Cookies. Sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide different URLs for different languages.

```
/en-us/page1
/en-us/page2
/en-us/page3
/es-es/page1
/es-es/page2
/es-es/page3
```

Then just use relative URLs between them.

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="page1">Page 1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="page2">Page 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="page3">Page 3</a> </li>
</ul>

<a href="../es-es/page1" lang="es-es" hreflang="es-es">español</a>
```

Comment: Yes. (Obviously, using software to manage this would be easier than doing it by hand though).

Comment: That would fall under the category of "using software to manage this". SPAs are really complicated to do right though — their benefits are about performance not easy of maintenance/development. It would be easier with a traditional server-side CMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"> 
</script>
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

This uses google translate which shows a drop down list of languages.

ref. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp